# How to get a Sum() from a List<> depending on the order of an string[] array

Tags: c#, arraylist, sum, console-application

I'm trying to get the `Sum()` of a `List<>` depending on the `string[]` of an array. I tried the following method:

```
private static List<int> sum = new List<int>();
private static int total = 0;
private static string[] ErrorCode = new string[] {"@", "-2", "!"};

private static void Score(string[] ErrorCode)
{
        if (ErrorCode.Contains("@"))
        {
            sum.Add(1);
        }
        if (ErrorCode.Contains("-2"))
        {
            sum.Add(-2);
        }

        if (ErrorCode.Contains("!"))
        {
            sum.Clear();
            sum.Add(5);
        }

        total = sum.Sum(); 
        //This prints total = 5
}
```

However, if the array is ordered a different way like:

```
private static string[] ErrorCode = new string[] {"!", "-2", "@"};

private static void Score(string[] ErrorCode)
{
        if (ErrorCode.Contains("@"))
        {
            sum.Add(1);
        }
        if (ErrorCode.Contains("-2"))
        {
            sum.Add(-2);
        }

        if (ErrorCode.Contains("!"))
        {
            sum.Clear();
            sum.Add(5);
        }

        total = sum.Sum(); 
        //This prints total = 5 
        //but should print total = 4 (because of the order of the array)
}
```

How can I achieve a result that dynamically prints either value? So, it would depend on how the array was entered with the ErrorCode and not on the Score method `if statements`. 
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: To be clear to readers, can you put the inputs, the outputs you are getting, and the outputs you would like to get. I know you have this information in there, it just takes a few reads to understand it

Comment: @MichaelRandall Sure, I'll edit the question to show the second case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Contains` when order matters, process each command in order:

```
private static void Score(string[] ErrorCode) {
    total = 0;
    foreach (var ec in ErrorCode) {
        switch (ec) {
            case "@":
                total += 1;
                break;
            case "-2":
                total += -2;
                break;
            case "!":
                total = 5;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also have `Score` use a local variable (`sum`?) and return the result when done. You should name `ErrorCode` as `errorCodes` as it contains multiple codes, so:

```
private static int Score(string[] errorCodes) {
    var sum = 0;
    foreach (var ec in errorCodes) {
        switch (ec) {
            case "@":
                sum += 1;
                break;
            case "-2":
                sum += -2;
                break;
            case "!":
                sum = 5;
                break;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

total = Score(ErrorCodes);
```